# C# - can't create method in main class?

Tags: c#

```
namespace FruitGarden
{
    class FruitGarden
    {
        private void MakeFruitBaskets()
        {
        private FruitBasket basket1 = new FruitBasket();
        private FruitBasket basket2 = new FruitBasket();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error "} expected" after the opening bracket of my MakeFruitBaskets method even though the method is closed properly. Help?

Comment: you can not have modifier to the variables inside the method.

Comment: Is your intention to use these baskets throughout the class? or only during that one method, at the moment there scope is limited to that method (and as mentioned, don't need the `private`)

Answer (score 4):

Remove `private` from `FruitBasket` declaration.

```
    private void MakeFruitBaskets()
    {
         FruitBasket basket1 = new FruitBasket();
         FruitBasket basket2 = new FruitBasket();
    }
```

I think what you really try to achieve look something like below. As you can see now we can use `private` because we **declare** `FruitBasket` as **fields**. And we **instantiate** them in `MakeFruitBaskets` method.

```
namespace FruitGarden
{
    class FruitGarden
    {
        private FruitBasket basket1; // Field
        private FruitBasket basket2; // Field

        public FruitGarden() // Constructor
        {
             MakeFruitBaskets();
        }

        private void MakeFruitBaskets()
        {
            basket1 = new FruitBasket();
            basket2 = new FruitBasket();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FruitGarden fruitGarden = new FruitGarden();
            // Use fruitGarden
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sayse you might be right, maybe he try to use them as **fields** and just instantiate them for a later usage.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `private` in `private FruitBasket`. You can't have access modifiers at local variables of methods.